# WordPress 3.3.1 single post template

Tags: wordpress, themes

Does anybody have any idea why on single posts there are no template dropdowns for template selections in WP 3.3.1? I did not find that either in the page administrative area.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wordpress doesn't offer this feature from the start. You need to install a plugin or you can edit single.php in your template folder.

For example (per category):

```
if (in_category('cat_1')) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-1.php');
} elseif (in_category('cat_2')) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-2.php');
} else{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-3.php');
}
```